# Redirects in Drupal for index.php and home in htaccess

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, redirect, drupal-6

I have been trying to create redirects for /home and /index.php to the site's base url. I have tried following rules in htaccess but without any effect

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\index.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ /
```

Im new to it so kindly bear with me if its a trivial question for the experts

Thanks in advance to the wonderful people here that are kind enough to help.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to redirect www.site.com/home and www.site.com/index.php to www.site.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work. All requests for nonexistent files and directories (like /node/42) are in fact redirected to /index.php (like /index.php?q=node/42). This whole mechanism breaks down if you try to redirect away from index.php.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with Drupal and the htacess.

The htacess allows for internal and external rewriting.

The below code will 301 redirect any request to the root index.php page to your web root. You should place these rules prior to Drupal's htacess internal rewriterule that essentially points everything to index.php:

```
#Redirect requests to index.php to / (Added for SEO URL canonicalisation)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L] 

#Drupals internal rewrite rules:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```